# Prevent views being pushed off screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to have 3 LinearLayouts ordered horizontally (basically forming three columns) within another LinearLayout where the width of the middle layout can vary depending on it's content.

All columns should be visible at all times filling the viewport from left. The left and irght column will be assigned a max width. So only the size of middle layout varies. If the total width of all columns exceeds the viewport size the middle column must not overlap or push out the other columns. But instead it should use the remaining space.

I tried using layout weights but that would put the right column always on the right side and the middle column would fill up all the space even though it's content would not require that.

When I try to use a RelativeLayout as a container I either end up with all three columns overlapping each other or the first column disappears.

I thought the below code (only schematic for now, as I don't have access to the code atm) should work, but as written above the first LinearLayout does not show up. The last LinearLayout seems to be in place as desired.

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_alignParentStart>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_alignParentEnd>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Please let me know if you need more detailed code examples etc. I will try to provide them as soon as possible.

I found a few other questions concerning this or similar topics but the solutions always used either layout weights or something like the code snippet above. So far I had no luck with those approaches, maybe because those questions  where either for slightly different use cases or a few years old so that the api has changed in the mean time.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works.

Using the layout_weight as describe by Jeffrey Blattman alone does only work when the views get large enough to fill the screen.

But as long as the views only fill a part you get gaps between them as the middle view fills up the remaining space. This is something I want to avoid in this case.

For some other reason I had to put my layout into a fragment. Now when I set the dimensions of the fragment to wrap_content the behavior is exactly as I want it. So the views do not get blown up while they are to small but are laid out as if there was no layout_weight defined. But still when growing larger the edge views stay within the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You want to defined the center columns with a `layout_width="0dp"` and a `layout_weight="1"`. The left and right columns will be `layout_width="wrap_content"`.

A `LinearLayout` should contain the 3 inner "column" `LinearLayout`s.

Comment: This does work when the middle column gets large and would then push the right one off the screen. But if the middle column is small it still puts the right column all the way to the right leaving the middle column to take up all the remaining space. I was looking for a way to avoid that.